Pass Keycloak IDToken through vouch and nginx
I am using vouch to handle an OpenId connection to Keycloak. Vouch allows me to centralize the authentication to two different apps.
I use vouch-proxy in latest version to redirect to the keycloak authentication. Keycloak sends an access_token to vouch, which I forward to the different applications as a Bearer header.
I recently upgraded Keycloak and it broke my logout. Keycloak now needs an IDToken in order to handle correctly the logout redirection. I added this to my Vouch configuration :
vouch:
  loglevel: debug
  allowAllUsers: true
  cookie:
    secure: false
    domain: localdev.e-cervo.com
  headers:
    claims:
        - preferred_username
        - domain
    accesstoken: X-Vouch-IdP-AccessToken
    idtoken: X-Vouch-IdP-IdToken
  post_logout_redirect_uris:
    - http://localdev.e-cervo.com/keycloak/auth/realms/cprocess/protocol/openid-connect/logout
    - /keycloak/auth/realms/cprocess/protocol/openid-connect/logout

In my nginx file I succeeded in getting the idtoken on a /logout request but I don't know what to do with it. Ideally I would like to pass it in the keycloak logout request but if I use a redirection, nginx does no longer retrieve the idtoken. It works only if I use proxy_pass like this :
location /logout {
        proxy_pass ${VOUCH_UPSTREAM};

        auth_request /validate;

        auth_request_set $auth_resp_x_vouch_idp_idtoken $upstream_http_x_vouch_idp_idtoken;

        add_header X-debug-IdToken $auth_resp_x_vouch_idp_idtoken;
        add_header X-debug-AccessToken $auth_resp_x_vouch_idp_accesstoken;
    }

I didn't find any simple and clean way to handle the IDToken for keycloak through vouch. Is there any ?
